# Adding Javascript to head of drupal page on form submit

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, drupal-6

There is a page with a `webform`, and I need to add the facebook conversion code to the header of the page that is shown when the form is submitted.

The problem is that they are the same page.

When I want to edit the page there is a 'Confirmation message' box, however that will add code to the `<body>` of the page and not the `<head>` as facebook asks you to do.

I also don't think i can put in the head of the page because then it will show up also when the form is loaded and not only when it is submitted.

I am also looking into the possibility of displaying it in the page only if the word "done" is in the url, but i'm not sure if that's possible, or if it's a bad idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using php to check the url of the page, and since we had the word 'done' in the url after the form was submitted, I could then add the code i needed.